writing remote keyboard for androidTV in android studio
I want to write a phone app to be used as a remote keyboard for androidTV. It will help parents to search for movies and other things without my help. So, there are a couple of questions:


What is the best way to make the connection to the TV? Is it via wifi network or something else?

Some have the ability to select a specific model of TV to control, but it's kind of for IR-transmitter built into some phones, so is it necessary to know the exact model of the TV to create a connection?

and maybe any tips on how to create a connection between the phone and the TV in android studio?
So far I've only implemented the visual and some minor functions, but basically how to establish a connection I don't really understand. Maybe plugins?



Are you writing apps for both the phone and the TV, and your question about "connection" is between the two apps? If so, how do you intend to have the TV app inject keystrokes into other apps? I don't know if Android TV supports third-party keyboard implementations, and other sorts of apps do not have the rights to inject input. Or, is your plan to have the phone become a Bluetooth HID input device, like a physical Bluetooth keyboard would be?

I don't quite understand how it's supposed to work. The main question is, what are the options for creating a connection? I have 2 TVs where the first one is just androidTV and the second one is samsungTV. Maybe there are some tools for the second one?

I recommend that you first determine how you are going to get keystrokes into other apps on the Android TV device. That is likely to significantly reduce your options for "connection", or it might mean that you will be unable to implement what you seek.
